# BigCartel Cart add a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, cart, bigcartel

I would add the option tag a class form-control.
The option tag have a id country.

```
{{ store.country | country_select }}
```

i try it with jquery but it didn't work.

```
$("#country").addClass("form-control");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That syntax looks correct, so as long as the rest of your code is functioning without errors you should see the class being added. You may want to make sure that you're initializing jQuery properly in your code, and calling addClass after the jQuery file is loaded too.

Can you provide a link to your store, or some further context of the code you're using?

Comment: I don't see jQuery being loaded at all in your store pages... I also see that the prototype javascript library is automatically included in your theme, so you'll need to make sure you add the `$.noConflict` code to properly execute any jQuery.

Comment: How i can load jQuery at all store pages?

Comment: You'll need to edit Customize Design > Advanced > Layout and include a link to the jQuery library in the `<head>` section of the code. You can learn how to incorporate jQuery to work with other libraries here: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/